# Using bfs coloring algorithm to check if graph is bipartite in Python

Tags: python, algorithm, graph, tree, bipartite

Code:

```
def bipartite(G):
    open_list = [1]
    colors = {}
    color_counter = 0
    # assign a color to the first node being visited
    colors[1] = 0

    while open_list:
        # up the counter here so that all neighbors get the same color
        color_counter += 1
        # use first elem for bfs
        current_neighbors = G[open_list[0]]
        current_color = color_counter % 2
        # prints used for debugging
        print open_list
        print "The current color is: %s" % (current_color,)
        for neighbor in current_neighbors:
            if neighbor not in colors:
                open_list.append(neighbor)
                colors[neighbor] = current_color
                # print used for debugging
                print "parent is: %s, child is: %s, %s's color is: %s" \
                % (open_list[0], neighbor, neighbor, colors[neighbor])
                # print used for debugging
            else: print "parent is: %s, child is: %s, already colored: %s" \
                % (open_list[0], neighbor, colors[neighbor])
        open_list.pop(0)
    # now, return array of values that has one of the two colors
    zeros_array = []
    ones_array = []
    for key in colors.keys():
        if colors[key] == 0:
            zeros_array.append(key)
        else:
            ones_array.append(key)

    if len(set(zeros_array) & set(ones_array)) == 0:
        return zeros_array
    else:
        return None
```

Here's the graph I'm using:

```
{1: {2: 1, 4: 1}, 2: {1: 1, 3: 1, 5: 1}, 3: {8: 1, 2: 1}, 4: {1: 1}, 5: {2: 1, 6: 1}, 6: {5: 1}, 8: {3: 1}}
```

I drew it out and the graph can be visualized as a tree with 1 as the root, and branches off to nodes 2 and 4, where 4 is a leaf, but 2 keeps going. I'm using a color counter to color neighbors the same color (either 0 or 1). 2 and 4 are given the same color, then the algorithm correctly gives 3 and 5 the opposite color of their parent 2, but when returning one level up to check 4, the color counter is incremented, so by the time it gets to 8, 8 gets the wrong color.

I'm stuck at how to best fix this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should choose the color in depending on the your current vertex color, something like `colors[neighbor] = (colors[open_list[0]] + 1) % 2`

Also, `len(set(zeros_array) & set(ones_array)) == 0` will always be `true`, so you aren't checking is bipartite has gone well. You could check it in else branch of `if neighbor not in colors:`: just assert that your neighbour has different color with current vertex.

Comment: Modified your line to: colors[neighbor] = (colors[open_list[0]] + 1) % 2 and it worked. Couldn't have gotten there without you, thanks!

Comment: Yeah, I've misspelled